# Как объединить две таблицы по двум столбцам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, обработка-данных

У меня есть 2 CSV файла, в которых имеются одинаковое количество столбцов:

```
Date Timestamp      Open      High       Low     Close   Volume
```

Я хочу отредактировать эти две таблицы и оставить только эти столбцы:

```
Date  Timestamp  Close
```

Затем объединить их по `Date` и `Timestamp`.

В конечном итоге хочу получить таблицу с такими столбцами:

```
Date  Timestamp Close_1 Close_2
```

Подскажите, как объединить две таблицы по двум столбцам?

Пример столбца:

```
                        Date Timestamp    Close
0                   20210104  03:00:00  1.22492
1                   20210104  03:01:00  1.22451
2                   20210104  03:02:00  1.22446
3                   20210104  03:03:00  1.22431
4                   20210104  03:04:00  1.22431
```

Нужно сопоставить данные с другой таблицей по дате и времени:

```
           Date Timestamp   Close_1  Close_2
0      20210104  03:00:00  1.22492  2.545
1      20210104  03:01:00  1.22451  2.457
2      20210104  03:02:00  1.22446  2.789
3      20210104  03:03:00  1.22431  2.547
4      20210104  03:04:00  1.22431  2.476
```

Comment: используйте метод `DataFrame.join` с ключом `on` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html )

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы привели пример данных хоть по три строки - что есть, что хочу получить.
А то кажется, что решение в две четыре строки
1. прочесть один файл  2. прочесть второй файл 3. объединить два файла  4. взять нужные столбцы... И все это Pandas

Comment: Подправил условие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cols = "Date Timestamp Close".split()
d1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, usecols=cols).rename(columns={"Close": "Close_1"})
d2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, usecols=cols).rename(columns={"Close": "Close_2"})
res = d1.merge(d2)
```